# Mixpanel: Distinct id is disregarded by Mixpanel

Tags: tracking, mixpanel

I track an event from my rails backend with this:
tracker.track(user.email, "Signup Success")

as expected, user.email contains the user's email address

But the event shows up in Mixpanel with this type of distinct id:
"14f13d5681xxxx-02558bcc3-797exxxx-fa000-14f13d5681xxxx"

Why is Mixpanel disregarding my specified distinct id (the user's email), and substituting its own? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
# This call will send a request to Mixpanel to
# associate all future events with new_internal_id
# with existing events associated with
# original_anonymous_id
tracker.alias(new_internal_id, original_anonymous_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem with distinct id. Try to concatenate any string to your email. Example:

```
String distinctEmail = "email: " + user.email; 
tracker.track(distinctEmail, "Signup Success");
```

I get same situation as you described. When hardcode distinct id everything work, but when pass email there is a problem. My solution is not "by the book" but at least in mixpanel show email plus added sting.

Let me know if this solution work for you.

I was in contact with MP Support and I will update my answer if I found proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to show your events in mixpanel with email address as unique id then use the Following code to solve your issue:

`mixpanel.identify(user.email);
mixpanel.track("Signup Success");`

Comment: That's a client-side example for Mixpanel. The `identify` function isn't available in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

The new Mixpanel [Identity Merge](https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039133851-Moving-to-Identity-Merge) concept behind this. Here is the explanation from the mixpanel dev.

https://community.mixpanel.com/data-management-10/interchanged-values-for-distinctid-and-distinct-id-before-identity-5606

[image]